# Cloudflare Worker fetch() global does not respect Cloudflare worker routes

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I have a web application that is proxied by Cloudflare running at `hybrid-app.example`

I am using the [Cloudflare Worker Sites](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/sites) pattern to host a static site at `hybrid-app.example/static-content/`. This worker is listening on the route `*hybrid-app.example/static-content*`. I can verify that this worker is configured correctly by navigating to `https://hybrid-app.example/static-content/hello.html`, and seeing the correct content from my static site.

I also have a second Cloudflare worker that uses the worker [Router pattern](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/templates/pages/router) to proxy select pages from the static site to vanity URLs on the same domain. In particular, this worker is configured to listen on the route `*hybrid-app.example/hello*`. Internally, it does the following:

```js
return fetch('https://hybrid-app.example/static-content/hello.html')
```

But when I navigate to `https://hybrid-app.example/hello`, I see a `GET` request to `/static-content/hello.html` hit my origin server. So it appears that when I called [`fetch`](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/fetch/) function in a Cloudflare worker, it is resolving the request without checking for matches against any other worker routes. Is there an alternative to the Fetch API I can use to force a request from one cloudflare worker to check for other matching CF worker routes before resolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible; Cloudflare workers always bypass Cloudflare (including the step where requests are routed to workers) [for requests in the same zone](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/issue-with-worker-to-worker-https-request/94472/8):

> Regarding worker composition (one worker invoking another worker):
>   such request chaining isn’t possible on same-zone subrequests.
>   Instead, we always send those to the origin. This limitation is in
>   place to resolve an ambiguity: how do we know that a subrequest is
>   “trusted” and should be sent directly to the origin, versus
>   “untrusted” and should go in the front door, running all Cloudflare
>   features (including Workers) from the start? (Note that this ambiguity
>   doesn’t exist for cross-zone subrequests: such subrequests are
>   obviously untrusted from the perspective of the other zone.)